# What are ways to better show depth along a 3D curve?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, curves

What are effective techniques for making the depth of a 3D curve clear when it twists and turns, making its depth ambiguous from a static perspective?

[image]

```
points = Table[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3], 25];
spline = BSplineFunction[points];
ParametricPlot3D[
  spline[t],
  {t, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}},
  Boxed -> False,
  AxesLabel -> {"u", "t", "s"},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  FaceGrids -> {{{0, 
      0, -1}, {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
       6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin],
  ViewPoint -> {5/6, -1.5, 0},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Ticks -> False,
  AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{{1/100, 1, arrow[]}}], Automatic}
  ] /. Line -> Arrow
```

Preferably *keeping* the presentation static, *e.g.* not animating it to spin, because then it would make the curve hard to trace and study by eye. Although, I remember seeing a technique where an image is animated to rotate back and forth just a small number of degrees—enough parallax to give the sense of depth—that might be fine, or at least interesting to see. But I'm more interested in general techniques—employing colors, lighting or shadows, opacity, and other properties I'm not imagining—that have been used in publications to address this exact issue.

Answer (score 17):

Try this for improved lighting and shading:

```
points = Table[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3], 25];
spline = BSplineFunction[points];
ParametricPlot3D[spline[t], {t, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}},
  Boxed -> False,
  AxesLabel -> {"u", "t", "s"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  FaceGrids -> {{{0, 
      0, -1}, {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
       6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 30]],
  ViewPoint -> {5/6, -1.5, 0}, ImageSize -> Large, Ticks -> False,
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
  ] /. Line -> (Tube[#, 0.1] &)
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

- Or colorize  along the curve.

```
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue@t], PlotStyle -> 
 Directive[Black, Thin, Tube[.1]], ColorFunctionScaling -> True
```

```
points = Table[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3], 25];
spline = BSplineFunction[points];
ParametricPlot3D[spline[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"u", "t", "s"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{{0, 
     0, -1}, {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
      6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}}, ViewPoint -> {5/6, -1.5, 0}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Ticks -> False, 
 AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{{1/100, 1}}], Automatic}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue@t], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin, Tube[.1]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image]

- inspire by @MelaGo, set `Method -> {"OneLayer" -> {"Depth", 1}}` as in the document of `Graphics3D`.

```
SeedRandom[4];
points = Table[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3], 25];
spline = BSplineFunction[points];
g = ParametricPlot3D[spline[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, Boxed -> False, 
   AxesLabel -> {"u", "t", "s"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, 
   FaceGrids -> {{{0, 0, -1}, {Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10]}}}, 
   Ticks -> False];
Show[g, Method -> {"OneLayer" -> {"Depth", 1}}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

- Using the `ClipPlanes` to clip some part of the curve along one direction in order to show the depth.
- Due to the **bug** of 14.0, the `ClipPlanesStyle` does not work(only 13,12,11 version work)

```
points = Table[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3], 25];
spline = BSplineFunction[points];
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[spline[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesLabel -> {"u", "t", "s"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  FaceGrids -> {{{0, 
      0, -1}, {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
       6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}}}, ViewPoint -> {5/6, -1.5, 0}, 
  Ticks -> False, AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{{1/100, 1}}], Automatic}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue@t], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin, Tube[.1]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ClipPlanes -> {0, -1, 0, d}, 
  ClipPlanesStyle ->{Directive[Opacity[.5], Gray]}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {d, 
  0, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can explore the various `MaterialShading` and `Lighting` options.

```
SeedRandom[1];
points = Table[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3], 25];
spline = BSplineFunction[points];

ParametricPlot3D[spline[t], {t, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {"u", "t", "s"},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 Boxed -> False,
 FaceGrids -> {{{0, 0, -1}, {Range[0, 10], Range[0, 10]}}},
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
 PlotRange -> {0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], Tube[0.15]}},
 Ticks -> False,
 ViewPoint -> {5/6, -1.5, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Huh, thank you for introducing me to `Lighting -> "ThreePoint"`. That looks really awesome!